# SVG won't render in Chrome/Brave but works perfectly fine in Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I managed to render my SVG file which I hosted through `gist.github` in Microsoft Edge but it does not work in Chromium browsers such as Brave and Chrome.

I tried everything to render it on Chrome but it just did not work. Is this a specific issue to the SVG file? I created the file using Inkscape and tried both SVG versions (Inkscape and Plain).

Here's the React Component

```
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
 
export default function Banner() {
  
  return (
    <Container >
      <Particles
        id="tsparticles"
        options={{
          background: {
            color: {
              value: "#000",
            },
          },
          detectRetina: false,
          fpsLimit: 60,
          interactivity: {
            detectsOn: "canvas",
            events: {
              onHover: {
                enable: true,
                mode: "bubble",
              },
              resize: true,
            },
            modes: {
              bubble: {
                distance: 40,
                duration: 2,
                opacity: 8,
                size: 6,
                speed: 3,
              },
            },
          },
          particles: {
            color: {
              value: "#ff0000",
              animation: {
                enable: true,
                speed: 20,
                sync: true,
              },
            },
            lineLinked: {
              blink: false,
              color: "random",
              consent: false,
              distance: 30,
              enable: true,
              opacity: 0.3,
              width: 0.5,
            },
            move: {
              attract: {
                enable: false,
                rotate: {
                  x: 600,
                  y: 1200,
                },
              },
              bounce: false,
              direction: "none",
              enable: true,
              outMode: "bounce",
              random: false,
              speed: 1,
              straight: false,
            },
            number: {
              density: {
                enable: false,
                area: 2000,
              },
              limit: 0,
              value: 200,
            },
            opacity: {
              animation: {
                enable: true,
                minimumValue: 0.05,
                speed: 1,
                sync: false,
              },
              random: false,
              value: 1,
            },
            shape: {
              type: "circle",
            },
            size: {
              animation: {
                enable: false,
                minimumValue: 0.1,
                speed: 40,
                sync: false,
              },
              random: true,
              value: 1,
            },
          },
          polygon: {
            draw: {
              enable: true,
              lineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)",
              lineWidth: 0.3,
            },
            move: {
              radius: 10,
            },
            inlineArrangement: "equidistant",
            scale: 0.3,
            type: "inline",
            url:
              "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gist/asralf90/22ed5c73043e9e2f4c7339de30fbc2fa/raw/8b7db616f49376f40d46c75ab13e95ab773d79d6/polygonmask2.svg",
          },
        }}
      />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can load the SVG just fine in chrome. I copy/pasted your code into a codesandbox and it throws error: "Cannot read property 'numberOfItems' of undefined" trying to process PolygonMask. If I comment out the `url` key-value for the linked SVG the particles load (sans the SVG though).

Comment: Yes it works if you open the SVG file in Chrome but it didn't work with the react-tsparticles dependency. Same thing happened to me but the whole code above works perfectly fine in Edge (running through localhost).  I don't know whether it's the browser or the SVG issue.

Comment: SVGs are *just* markup, so my money is on the SVG having some anomalies in it that chromium browsers may parse differently for some reason. The error is emanating from within particlejs though, perhaps starting there to see what is missing and/or unprocessable from the SVG markup. I know chrome and react can be a little particular about the extra attributes in SVGs, maybe try a simpler SVG, or manually sanitize the one you have.